# Import File from SharePoint and Link this file with SharePoint (File- Excel File)

Tags: 2013, development, list, excel, excel-services

I am using SharePoint 2013 and Microsoft Office 2007 or above.

Scenario:

1. I upload a Excel file to a SharePoint 2013 list.
2. Now, I want to import this Excel file from this SharePoint list back to Excel.
3. And link this imported Excel file with SharePoint.

And I don't want the SharePoint list to be imported in the Excel file, it is the Excel contents.

How can I do this?

Is this possible with all the MS office versions (2007, 2010 & 2013)?

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

Using Excel 2003 version, you can synchronize SharePoint list and the excel, in Office Excel 2007 and later on versions, you can no longer update a SharePoint list with changes that you make to the table data in Excel after that data has been exported.

For your scenario, you can make use of the OOTB "[Export to Excel](http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/excel-help/export-an-excel-table-to-a-sharepoint-list-HA010131472.aspx)" option in the SharePoint, it will create a new Excel Worksheet with the data in the SharePoint list and it has a link to the SharePoint list from which you have exported, When you refresh the table data in Excel, the latest data from the SharePoint site overwrites the table data on the worksheet, including any changes that you made to the table data.

Reference:

1. [How to Export Excel Sheet to SharePoint List](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/18705.sharepoint-2013-how-to-export-excel-sheet-to-sharepoint-list.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

According to a post on [Technet](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/37ec4075-d7ae-4fe8-b529-bcb191ce6e68/sp2010-infopath-2010-how-to?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious), an Excel add-in still works to synchronize lists and Excel tables in SharePoint 2010. I have not tried or tested it with SharePoint 2013, but it may be worth a go.

The tool: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=9345

The documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb462636(v=office.11).aspx

The essence of a list has not changed much from SharePoint 2007 to SharePoint 2013, so chances are that this will still work.